# Can this be done in a LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to map from a list of objects to another list of objects that are grouped by a property like below:

Select this list:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>() 
{ 
    new Product {Id = "1", Group = "1"},
    new Product {Id = "1", Group = "2"},
    new Product {Id = "1", Group = "3"},
    new Product {Id = "2", Group = "1"},
    new Product {Id = "2", Group = "2"},
    new Product {Id = "2", Group = "3"}
};
```

Into a list with objects grouped by Id like this:

```
List<ProductById> productsById = new List<ProductById> 
{
    new ProductById {Id = "1", Group1 = "1", Group2 = "2", Group3 = "3"},
    new ProductById {Id = "2", Group1 = "1", Group2 = "2", Group3 = "3"}
};
```

Can this be done by a LINQ statement on the first products list?

Comment: If you know there are only three groups, yes. Otherwise, you could have a `Groups` list instead of explicit 1, 2, 3.

Comment: @CoryNelson Yes the number of groups is static. How do you select the multiple Products into a single ProductById?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you're asking with LINQ but it's not clear why the groups are so static and only contain 1, 2, 3. But this will take your provided input and create your desired output:

```
public void Map()
{
    var products = new List<Product>()
    {
        new Product {Id = "1", Group = "1"},
        new Product {Id = "1", Group = "2"},
        new Product {Id = "1", Group = "3"},
        new Product {Id = "2", Group = "1"},
        new Product {Id = "2", Group = "2"},
        new Product {Id = "2", Group = "3"}
    };

    products.GroupBy(p => p.Id).Select(grp =>
    {
        var pById = new ProductById()
        {
            Id = grp.Key
        };
        pById.Group1 = grp.First(g => g.Group == "1").Group;
        pById.Group2 = grp.First(g => g.Group == "2").Group;
        pById.Group3 = grp.First(g => g.Group == "3").Group;
        return pById;
    });
}
```

If, however, your product by id should really be holding a `List<string>` for all the groups you input then it would look like this:

```
public class ProductById
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Groups { get; set; }
}

public void Map()
{
    var products = new List<Product>()
    {
        new Product {Id = "1", Group = "1"},
        new Product {Id = "1", Group = "2"},
        new Product {Id = "1", Group = "3"},
        new Product {Id = "2", Group = "1"},
        new Product {Id = "2", Group = "2"},
        new Product {Id = "2", Group = "3"}
    };

    products.GroupBy(p => p.Id).Select(grp =>
    {
        var pById = new ProductById()
        {
            Id = grp.Key,
            Groups = grp.Select(g => g.Group).ToList()
        };
        return pById;
    });
}
```